# Is there a journal or organization where one can submit (not necessarily professional) philosophical articles?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, publications

I am neither a professional philosopher nor an academic.
But I do seem to like to engage in philosophical thought
and sometimes have different ideas about different topics in life.

I was wondering if there are some organizations where you can submit your philosophical articles.

And which don't require the submitting persons to be professionals (e.g. familiar with all academic literature etc.). Maybe philosophy like for general public, etc.

PS I think I found one such cadidate:https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think
Your feedback on it and other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As far as Think, "*the central aim of the journal is to provide to a very wide audience... highly accessible and engaging writing by philosophers pre-eminent in their fields*", so this is not what you are looking for. Most publications do not require one to be a professional philosopher or an academic, but (good ones) do require background knowledge and quality, being familiar with relevant literature is part of it. Even if (and perhaps especially) when the work is aimed at non-professionals. For musings on different topics in life discussion forums are more suitable.

Comment: Write a blog, or make YouTube videos. If you can build an audience, then you can reason your thinking is intetesting to people.

Answer (score 1):

Such a nice digital magazine that I follow is https://aeon.co/philosophy. You may learn from https://aeon.co/author-terms to submit material.

For an academically oriented platform, you may wish to take a look at Open Philosophy at https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/opphil/opphil-overview.xml

Answer (score 1):

Yes Academia.com allows you to submit what appears to be papers but they don't have to be published. You can submit published ones also. You make a profile for yourself.